# Image to Text converter

Tags: images, ocr

I need a software which can convert scanned text to editable text. I will prefer freeware?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

my favorite:

**[TopOCR](http://www.topocr.com/)** is designed to be simple and user-friendly for use with your digital camera or smartphone. Now wherever you go, you can quickly and easily acquire documents from business cards, newspapers, books and magazines, without having to carry around a bulky and costly portable scanner.

of course it also works with images from a scanner.

TopOCR 3.1 Features

- **Incredible OCR accuracy**, upto 99.8% with a 3 MP camera
- No page limits, and no extra downloads or components needed
- Handles images with mixed text and graphics
- Handles skew and uneven lighting
- Output formats include searchable PDF and HTML
- Able to read 11 different languages
- Powerful, easy to use Image Processing
- Supports Smartphones: See some Smartphone samples
- Includes built-in Text and Image WYSIWYG Editors
- Post-processing spell checker for all 11 languages
- Built-in Text-To-Speech software. How about OCR to MP3?
- Browser Helper Mode supports creating free audio eBooks

[image]

*TopOCR is freeware, easy to make portable with Universal Extractor.*

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is [OCR (Optical Character Recognition)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) Software, If the scanned file is small, you can use an online tool called [Free OCR](http://www.free-ocr.com/).

For an application, I recommend [Paperfile's Free OCR](http://www.paperfile.net/). (Same name, different program).