# Edit text in image

Tags: adobe-acrobat, ocr

I have a JPG image with some text in it. I would like to edit this text.

I am currently using Adobe Acrobat for this purpose, however I found that the Text Recognition Tool will not recognize all text, even clear and obvious text. For example with the following image

[image: sample]

only the small font is being recognized. Am I missing something or is another program available that can handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the sounds of it, you either need to

1. use better OCR software to extract the text from the image ([Image to Text converter](https://superuser.com/questions/90504/image-to-text-converter) for example, or Google Drive/Docs built-in OCR https://support.google.com/drive/answer/176692?hl=en) and manipulate the text outside of the image or
2. you need to use a graphics editor to manipulate the image as an image, erasing the area showing the existing text and replacing it with new.

JPG files only maintain information regarding the colour and position of pixels within the image, there is no information held on font or text content or similar. Therefore you cannot change the text within a JPG directly because there is no text within the image, only an image of what the text looked like when it was saved.