# Quick copy text from image?

Tags: images, screenshot, productivity, ocr

Is there a method for quickly selecting an area of a picture / image and copying it into the clipboard as text?

For example, say someone lacking foresight sends me a screenshot of a console instead of the text file, and I want to copy a snippit into Google. Is there a tool / method for quickly parsing the outlined part of the image?
[image]
(image borrowed via Google images purely for example sake, credit [this page](http://blog.romant.net/technology/exception-error-creating-edge-vm/))

This would save me a lot of time from typing or going through the many clicks of uploading to some kind of image parsing program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image to Text converter](http://superuser.com/questions/90504/image-to-text-converter)

Comment: I would protest against this being considered off-topic, as I believe this is a valid user need and not simply a request for a product recommendation. I worded my question to allow for non-product solutions, but (as with most questions) there may, of course, be a product solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like [Capture2Text](http://capture2text.sourceforge.net/) might do what you want. Its an open source program I found when looking for something similar for work.

Short instruction (fetched straight from the site)

1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> to start the capture.
2. Now, using your mouse, resize the capture box over the area of the screen
   that you want to OCR.
3. A preview of the captured OCR'd text will appear in the top-left
   corner of the screen.
4. Press the capture key again or the left mouse button to complete the
   capture.
5. The captured screen area will be OCR'd and the textual result will
   be stored in the clipboard by default.